# To save attachments from outlook to a particular folder

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Trying to save attachments from Outlook to a particular folder, the code saves the first attachment in a particular mainbut if it has more than 1 attachment it leaves other attachment.. tried using loop but it shows errors

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim MailBoxName         As String
Dim Pst_Folder_Name     As String
Dim Pst_SubFolder_Name     As String
Dim val
Dim strFile As String

 'Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object
   ' Dim oOlItm As Object

Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFolderpath As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

MailBoxName = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value
Pst_Folder_Name = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value
If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3).Value <> "" Then
    Pst_SubFolder_Name = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3).Text
    Set Folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name).Folders(Pst_SubFolder_Name)

Else
    Set Folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)

End If
val = 1


Dim myOutlook As Object: Set myOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Dim myNameSpace As Object: Set myNameSpace = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'Dim MailFolder As Object: Set MailFolder = myNameSpace.Folders("Folder")

' Set the Attachment folder.
strFolderpath = "C:\Projects\Savefile\"

        '~~> Check if the email actually has an attachment
            For Each objMsg In Folder.Items

                If objMsg.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
                    '''''For each statement
                    i = objMsg.Attachments.Count
                    '~~> Download the attachment
                        For val = 1 To i
                        Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
                        strFile = strFolderpath & objAttachments.Item(val).Filename
                        objAttachments.Item(val).SaveAsFile strFile
            val = val + 1

            Next

            End If


ErrorHandler:
Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What errors do you see?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with an unknown amount of items in a collection - use a `For Each` loop instead:

```
For Each objAtt In objMsg.Attachments
    strFile = strFolderpath & objAtt.Filename
    objAtt.SaveAsFile strFile
Next
```

---

But to answer your question, specific to your existing code - get rid of this:

```
val = val + 1
```

You're already using `val` as a loop variable, by incrementing it inside the loop you're effectively skipping a number each time:

```
For val = 1 To 10
    Debug.Print val
Next
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

---

```
For val = 1 To 10
    Debug.Print val
    val = val + 1
Next
```

Output:

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

---